# Find text in the textbox in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I've come to realize the Excel "Find and Replace" dialog couldn't find text in the textboxes.
I think I need a macro to solve this.

How could I find text in the textboxes:

1. in the active sheet
2. in all sheets

Thank you.

Here's a sample image to show what I mean by textbox:
[image: Image of a textbox in Excel]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you only use text fields (and no other Objects) this code should work for you (I didn't try it on Excel 2016 though):

```
Sub Search()
    Dim shaShape As Shape
    For Each shaShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
        If shaShape.DrawingObject.Text Like "*all*" Then  '<== specify you're search term
            shaShape.Select
            Exit For
        End If
    Next shaShape
End Sub
```

Comment: It works but with some issues. It will only located to the first match. What if I want to keep searching to see if there is any other matches? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean? do you have an example?

Comment: Just like the "Find" function in the excel, it will go to the next match if I press the "Find next". However the script does not have such a function. Let's say there are 10 textboxes in all worksheets, 3 of them contain the word "all". The script only goes to the first match. There is no way to "find next" and goes to the other matches. I hope it is clear now. Thank you.

Comment: @masterton You will have to modify the code, how much do you know about VBA?

Comment: Next to nothing. I don't know how to code. Sometimes I just guess what the macro is trying to do and tweak a bit by trial and error.

Comment: @masterton ah, ok. In this case you should first try it to learn a little bit about VBA, you can use my code as a starting point. Try to understand what it does and then try edit it yourself (you can ask further questions here if you come across problems you can't solve yourself). It won't be that difficult. This site promotes mainly OPs who try to solve the question themselves (beside just asking for a solution). Or the easy way out: there are plenty of programmers out there (including myself) who will write it for you, your requirement shoudn't be to expensive.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm volunteering for the charity non-profit organization. I don't think they have budgets to hire a programmer to write codes. I asked this question because their spreadsheets have textboxes. I will try to learn when I have more free time, but it looks like pretty difficult to me.

Comment: @masterton it's not that difficult, as I said, just use my example as a starting point. Also there are a few VBA communities out there. You should get fairly good examples there as well and they will help you with the code much more then it is considered to be acceptable here.

Answer (score 0):

You can check another solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63436101/13426723).

It exports all the shapes (including textboxes) to a new Word document.

In Word the search function DOES work in textboxes and the problem is solved.

Answer (score -1):

check this out i think it has what you want
https://excel.tips.net/T011281_Finding_Text_in_Text_Boxes.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: And direct people to the right links. Yours is for Excel versions up to 2003, same author has another article for 2007+ https://excelribbon.tips.net/T011282_Finding_Text_in_Text_Boxes